# Fizzbuzz switch statement

Tags: ruby, switch-statement, fizzbuzz

Long question but I think it is odd. I was playing around with ruby switch statements. Created a little fizzbuzz function to practice.

Initially created the code like this

```
def fizzbuzz(start_num, end_num)
    fizzbuzz = []
    (start_num..end_num).each do |x|
        if x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 != 0
            fizzbuzz << "fizz"
        elsif x % 5 == 0 && x % 3 != 0
            fizzbuzz << "buzz"
        elsif (x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0) 
            fizzbuzz << "fizzbuzz"
        else
            fizzbuzz << x.to_s
        end
    end
    fizzbuzz 
end
```

Works as expected. Then wanted to play with a switch statement. So I tried:

```
def fizzbuzz(start_num, end_num)
fizzbuzz = []
(start_num..end_num).each do |x|
    case x
    when x % 3 == 0 
        fizzbuzz << "fizz"
    when x % 5 == 0 
        fizzbuzz << "buzz"
    when (x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0) 
        fizzbuzz << "fizzbuzz"
    else
        fizzbuzz << x.to_s
    end
end
fizzbuzz
```

end

This time the code only prints out the number converted to a string. Then mistakenly I tried to add && to the end of every when statement like so

```
def fizzbuzz(start_num, end_num)
    fizzbuzz = []
    (start_num..end_num).each do |x|
        case x
        when x % 3 == 0 &&
            fizzbuzz << "fizz"
        when x % 5 == 0 &&
            fizzbuzz << "buzz"
        when (x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0) &&
            fizzbuzz << "fizzbuzz"
        else
            fizzbuzz << x.to_s
        end
    end
    fizzbuzz 
end
```

Interestingly this prints out the correct result. It is probably a trivial answer, but does anyone know why this is the case? It seems rather odd to me.

Comment: Because a switch statement will only execute one branch, and you need this to hit multiple. FizzBuzz isn't a great use-case for `case`

Comment: @Brennan It isn't, but that's not the issue here; the OP's code doesn't require any fall-through behavior. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your point.

Comment: I misread at first. It's not THE issue, and once fixed will work, but it still shows a misunderstanding of how this structure works. It doesn't *require* any fall-through behavior, but he is certainly trying to use it as such.

Comment: @Brennan I think it's more a logic error than anything else; if OP was trying to rely on fall-through he'd get all three, `fizz`, `buzz`, and `fizzbuzz` appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `when` statements are doing a logical `&&`.

This has the side effect of concatenating your output when the condition is true.

The question you're *actually* asking, based on your comment, is what's going on with the `when` statements not seeming to work. The problem is that you wrote `case x`, which is evaluating `x` on-the-spot and comparing it to the `when` expressions.

Instead, use a "naked `case`", e.g.,

```
case
when (x % 3) == 0
  # etc
```

Note also that this could be wrapped up a bit tighter, e.g.,

```
def fizzbuzz(start_num, end_num)
  (start_num..end_num).collect do |x|
    case
      when (x % 3) == 0
        "fizz"
      when (x % 5) == 0
        "buzz"
      when (x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0)
        "fizzbuzz"
      else
        x.to_s
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For the last piece of code, let's see one `when` condition in detail:

```
when x % 3 == 0 &&
    fizzbuzz << "fizz"
```

Despite the indentation, it's equivalent to:

```
when x % 3 == 0 && fizzbuzz << "fizz"
```

Remember that `&&` is short-circuit. The `&&` expression returns its first argument if it is false. Otherwise, its second argument is evaluated and returned as the result.

So if `x % 3 == 0` is false, then `fizzbuzz << "fizz"` is not executed. If `x % 3 == 0` is true, `fizzbuzz << "fizz"` is executed. Exactly what is expected.

Comment: Understood, however the part that confuses me, I guess not asked in the original question, is why the original switch statement did not execute `fizzbuzz << "fizz"` even though the `when x % 3 == 0` was true?

Comment: @AlexKonetchy Because that's not how Ruby `case` statements work; since you wrote `case x` it's comparing `x` to the value of the `when` expression.